# Read u-LAW encoded WAV file and save it with no compression

Tags: python, audio, wav

I have a WAV file that has been compressed using u-LAW encoding, and I need it to have no compression at all because `wavio` doesn't support compressed files.

I have looked into `audioop` that [claims to support this kind of compression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/audioop.html#module-audioop):

> This module provides support for a-LAW, u-LAW and Intel/DVI ADPCM encodings.

Apparently, the function `audioop.ulaw2lin()` does exactly what I need, but I don't understand how to read my file to pass it to that function.

I have tried the following:

```
import wave
wav_file = wave.open(PATH_TO_AUDIO_FILE)
```

But, as I stated above, due to the fact that the audio is in u-LAW encoding, that piece of code raises an exception:

```
Error: unknown format: 7
```

Does anyone know how to perform this operation?

Answer (score 0):

`audioloop` gets raw bytes as an input, so you'll have to open the `wav` file as raw binary file and extract only the data, without the file's header.
The algorithm is:

1. Open the compressed file.
2. Read the data chunk.
3. Convert to PCM.
4. Add `wav` header.

Usually the `wav` header is 44 bytes long, so to get the data part:

```
with open('input.wav') as f:
    f.seek(44, os.SEEK_SET)
    data = f.read  # Caution here!
```

You may have to read the data in smaller chunks in order not to get some memory exception.
Now you can convert the data -

```
converted_data = audioloop.ulaw2lin(data, width)
```

where `width` is the desired output width - 1 for 8 bits and 2 for 16 bits.
For writing the data into a valid `wav` file, I recommend using `scipy` - it has a [wave module](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.wavfile.write.html).

Comment: I'm getting the following exception: `'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 8171: character maps to <undefined>`. Do you know what encoding I should use when opening the file?

Comment: I think you should open it as binary file - `open(''input.wav', 'rb')`.

Comment: When I try to save `converted_data` using `scipy.io.wavfile.write("output.wav", 8000, converted_data)` I get another exception: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'dtype'`.

Comment: Well, `scipy.io.wavfile.write` should get `nd.array` as the data, so you'll have to cast your `converted_data`. I think [this link](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html#numpy.frombuffer) might help.

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this problem for a long time, but I solved it using `ffmpeg`

On Ubuntu `ffmpeg` can be installed by:

```
sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Then to convert *raw G.711 μ-law* to *wav* simply use this command (if you want another sample rate, just replace `44100` in command):

```
ffmpeg -f mulaw -ar 44100 -i input_raw_g711u_file output_file.wav
```

Now you can open `output_file.wav` just like a normal wav file.

If you want to convert it in Python, just use `subprocess` or `os` module to call this command.